# Apply dxhold/touch event of phonejs on d3 node

Tags: d3.js, phonejs

Making mobile application with **phonejs**, I'm using **d3.js** with force layout. I want to add some functionality when node of *d3* is double-tapped or held-with-tap. 
But double-click event does not do anything in phone. I also tried jQuery touch events but didn't work here. 
How can I put touch event on node of *d3*?

Here is the node:

```
node = container.append("g").selectAll("image.node")
      .data(nodes_edges_json.nodes)
      .enter().appent("g").append("svg:image")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(nodeObj) { return setImage(nodeObj); })
      .attr("width", function(nodeObj) { return setHeightWidth(nodeObj); })
      .attr("height", function(nodeObj) { return setHeightWidth(nodeObj); })
      .on("dblclick", function(data, index) {
           d3.event.preventDefault();
           getdata(data, index);
       });
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895682/is-there-a-tap-and-double-tap-event-in-d3-js) should help.

Comment: I tried that but didn't work..@Lars Kotthoff

Comment: Have you tried to use `touchstart`?

Comment: touchstart event is identified but I want taphold or double-tab event on node..@MacroCI

Comment: I think you have to use another library to support that, because you need timers for that. For double tap have a look to this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479236/d3-js-double-tap while for tap hold this one could be useful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript

More, have a look to this gist: http://bl.ocks.org/eweitnauer/7144421

Comment: Thanks @MarcoCl... mouseup and mousedown events worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

I would make a suggestion that you look into http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/ I had the same issue and had to go against using the dxhold option. Hammer worked great though.