# Can I disable only double-tap zoom and not pinch zoom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pinchzoom, mobile-browser

I am making a game in Javascript, therefore it can be played on a computer or a mobile web browser. It is perfect on the computer, but it requires a lot of clicking.

When I use a mobile web browser, this is sometimes interpreted as a double-tap and keeps zooming, which I don't want.

I know how to disable zooming completely, but is there any way to disable double-tap zoom only? If not, is there a work-around to not keep zooming when I tap the movement buttons a lot?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10614481/1032493

Comment: @dmk Thanks! Now I need to get people to close my question as a duplicate :P

Comment: @VincentPiel Did what?

Comment: "I need to get people to close my question as a duplicate".

Comment: @VincentPiel Did you closevote?

Comment: i signaled the post to moderators as possible duplicate. Best i could do to help.

Comment: @Abe Well that was out of nowhere... so you just downvote every dup? Ok, up to you how you spend your votes