# How can I Block right click and double tap to zoom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows-8, touch

Gaming is really really fun when you have to tap and hold to do something, and it activates a context menu. Or when you double tap on a game to do an action and it zooms in.

So when I embed a HTML5 game using an iframe, how do I stop right click and double tap to zoom so that the player of the game is not annoyed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614481/disable-double-tap-zoom-option-in-browser-on-touch-devices

Comment: Alexander: I tried that on multiple elements on my webpage and it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Use FastClick https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick .. it eliminate the 300ms delay between a physical tap and the firing of a click event on mobile browsers.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
}, false);
```