# Is it possible to load a responsive iframe within a non-responsive site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Before you mark this as duplicated, let me tell you that this is not about making an iframe rescalable, and I'm not expecting this kind of answers: [Making an iframe responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838607/making-an-iframe-responsive)

My problem is easy to explain: I got a site without the `meta` viewport tag and a width of (lets say) 1000px. Therefore, when you load it in a mobile device, it rescales to fit the 360px width, and **everything is very small**.

Now, I perfectly know how to make an iframe to adjust to any width but the problem here is that the site being loaded will also be displayed with a width of 1000px even if this one has the `meta` viewport tag. Of course, everything in this iframe is shown very small as well.

Now the question: can I make the content of that iframe to be displayed at full width and yet **obey not the width of the parent document but the width of the device**. (obviously I don't want a small 360px iframe).

This may help you understand: [image]

**EDIT: Many people doesn't seem to understand this, so another way to explain it is this:**

1. Pick any site that doesn't have the viewport tag
2. Paint a fixed frame on it
3. And try to make that iframe look like if it was opened on a new tab
   (by default the iframe's viewport will be like 1000px, I'd like it to be the phone's viewport sizes)

Comment: can you post a sample plunkr or something? (from the mockups it looks like you need to increase the height of the iframe as well, so that the iframe itself has the same aspect ratio as your phone screen)

Comment: No no, forget about the height, height do nothing to do here. You may b confused by the so called "real content view", with that I just mean how the real web is displayed if opened on a tab instead of the iframe

Comment: well, if you want an answer you'll need to show us the code then... as i said, plunkr/jsfiddle whatever...

Comment: @mb21 what about a site?

Comment: maybe... :P it helps to have a mcve, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the problem is that fiddles and codepens already use iframes, so that is not very reliable!

Comment: Can you provide more details on the problems your are having with height and width? Are they set in px or relative units?

Comment: Why do you want to mixed device scaled content with non-scaled content? I suggest redesigning your main page to be truly responsive and include the meta viewport tag to get the most reliable presentation of the iframe content.

Comment: Because I'm doing a script to make the iframe work on any kind of page, obviously... If I'd do those websites myself I'd twist my brains this way, hahhaha Furthemore @IMI, it doesn't matter if this shouldn't be done, this is a user case and a problem that may be or may be not solved... So it is a perfectly valid question

Comment: You should have used a "Javascript" tag on this question because there is no strictly CSS method to do what you want. You want something like this: https://css-tricks.com/cross-domain-iframe-resizing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I first read your question I said no, this isn't possible, but then I started thinking and I believe I found a way. It requieres Javascript.

First we need to get two values, the document width and the device screen width. As per your example 1000px and 360px respectively.

We can get the doc width (1000px) with `document.documentElement.clientWidth` and the screen width (360px) with `window.screen.availWidth`

```
var dw = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var sw = window.screen.availWidth;
```

Once we have those two values, we can get the `scale` of the viewport

```
var scale = dw/sw;
```

And last we set the width of the iframe to the width of the screen (360px) to then scale it up to the previously calculated `scale`. We use CSS transformations for this.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('theIframe');
iframe.style.width = dw + 'px';
iframe.style.transform = 'scale(' + scale + ')';
```

You still need to center the iframe so that it shows in the position you want. You can use `iframe.style.transformOrigin = '0 0'` for this or any other method like `translate(w/2, h/2)` or `top:w/2; height:h/2` (pseudo code).

Also, you might need to use browser prefixes for some devices, i.e. `style.webkitTransform` instead of `style.transform`.

To calculate the height of your iframe you could do

```
var dh = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
iframe.style.height = (0.5 * dh / scale) + 'px'; // percentage based
// or...
iframe.style.height = (600 / scale) + 'px'; // pixel based
```

This is supposing you want use 50% or 600px for the height.

Let me know if you need me to elaborate more and good luck!

Comment: You are in the right direction, but you should add  `iframe.style.transformOrigin = "0% 0%";`  and you need to add +"px" to the width. Also, how would you calc the height?

Comment: Yes, you can use transformOrigin (as I suggested) or also translate or top/left. This is up to you ;) For the height, if you want % use `dw*myPercentage*scale` or `myPixels*scale` for px. I'll update my answer to add this info. Cheers

Comment: I also noticed that it is important to prevent double tap from scaling, as some strange behaviour is shown as consecuence

Comment: Good point. I imagine some of the zooming coordinates get messed up with the transformation. Not sure you can prevent double tap.

Comment: Found this thread. Maybe you'll be able to disable double tap zooming with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10910547/267995

Answer (score 6):

If I understood correctly what you are asking, **yes** it is possible, but since I can't replicate the situation in a fiddle, here is below the code I've tested with success:

### The non-responsive site (no meta `viewport` linked)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>The non-responsive site</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#wrapper {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
iframe {
    max-width:1000px;
    width:100%;
    margin:10px auto;
    display:block;
    min-height:400px;
    border:0 
}
</style>
</head>   
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae orci a velit pretium commodo. Vivamus ultrices auctor lectus, non semper ipsum dictum eu. Integer nulla arcu, bibendum ac hendrerit at, scelerisque in augue. Proin a nisi et purus pulvinar blandit. Nulla ac diam congue, malesuada nunc vitae, aliquam quam. Praesent volutpat turpis eu orci volutpat iaculis. Vivamus tempus varius sagittis. Sed sollicitudin, dui ac finibus placerat, ante metus volutpat dui, eu feugiat ipsum erat nec libero. Quisque eu viverra ex, sit amet congue orci. Cras porta dignissim diam, in eleifend urna vulputate sit amet. Mauris in malesuada ligula, eget facilisis nisl. Maecenas non enim orci. Nullam porttitor fringilla velit a sodales. Suspendisse et accumsan mauris. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. 
    </div>
    <iframe src="responsive-iframe.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

### The responsive-iframe (meta `viewport` linked)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

p {
    color:red;
    font-size:32px;
    background-color:#FEB1C7
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    p {
        color:green;
        font-size:48px;
        background-color:#CF0
    }
}
</style>
</head> 
<body>
    <p>I'm green below 480px width, otherwise I'm red</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** the CSS above in `<head>` tag was just a quick way to make this demo, I always recommend to use external CSS files.

---

**UPDATE:** (I updated the code to match the SS's below)

- ScreenShot for the **NON-RESPONSIVE site**

[image]

---

- ScreenShot for the **iframe-responsive site**

[image: iFRAME-RESPONSIVE]

---

Comment: Your solution just shows that an iframe with the viewport tag respects media querys on rescale but this is not at all what my question was about. Please, read carefully, I'm asking for an iframe that isn't reescaled with the rescaling of the top page if the last doesn't have the meta viewport tag. In your case, although the iframe changes with the size of the page, it is as small as the rest of the things. I want it to be displayed big, like if you'd load it in a different window.

Comment: So if you want to keep the `iframe` with a fixed `width` it wont respect the media queries. Have you tried my code with your current project? Because you will get  the desired image you show in your question, if you have your `media queries`done correctly

Comment: no no no, I'd get the first picture which is the case I started with, and I want the 3rd one

Comment: I put my code [here](http://serpa.eusou.com/so/a1s2d3.html) and this really looks like the 3rd not the 1st image

Comment: Using media queries has no mystery. What I'm asking is to lead any page and display it without zoom even en pages that are zoomed automaticly by the browser

Comment: Both pages haven't any zoom at all, I really can't understand what are you trying to achieve then.

Comment: mobile browsers try to fit websites without meta viewport tag and wide widths on the screen by zooming them out. The problem is that the size and content of the iframe is also diminished, as the iframe belongs to the top page and its sizes are defined there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79965/discussion-between-dippas-and-vandervals).

Comment: He wants to mixed device scaled content with non-device scaled content. With your demo, the desire would be to see the Green text when viewed on a mobile device. But since most devices will scale the content only the Red text will be visible.

Comment: @IMI But in my demo you will see green with mobile devices. Am i the only one here who's seeing that??? Do I need to take ScreenShots??

Comment: @dippas I' don't see that, can you make some screenshots?

Comment: @dippas, my question is trying to find a solution for the first screenshot of yours to be green, not the second one!

Comment: @Vandervals come [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79965/discussion-between-dippas-and-vandervals)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it if you are able to change the iframe's css to use **min-device-width** media queries and **[viewport sized typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)**. This should make it responsive by the device and the viewport sized typography will adjust things accordinging to percentage of device width instead of using the "Browser Scaled" text.

Below is a CSS example:

```html
@media only screen and (min-device-width:25em) {
  body {font-size:3vw; line-height:3.9vw;}
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will only affect the fontsize, but won't affect to the widths and heights as they are not always in %

Comment: Please update your question with some specific code examples. It is difficult to offer any more detailed advice without seeing the css of the page that is to be inside the iframe. I am assuming that you are creating the content of the iframe. If that is true, I strongly recommend using % for your container elements if you want your content to be truly adaptive.

Comment: It is not the inside page what matters as an iframe may load anything you want

Comment: It does matter. Small mobile devices often scale the content of a page that is not designed to be responsive. The content of the iframe will also be scaled unless it was designed to be responsive using a "device" based media query.

Comment: you are not getting the point here. The question is about an **iframe that can load anything**  and how to configure the top page with css and js so that the iframe, no is viewed no-scaled **even when the top page is scaled**

Comment: This is the closest of my desired answer but it would be important to solve the problem of the widths...

Answer (score 0):

What you actually look for is an iframe within iframe. The main html will not call the target directly but rather use:

```
<iframe id="myviewport" src="myviewport.html" seamless />
```

The file `myviewport.html` will be for example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1000, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://target.example.com">
</body>
</html>
```

You own `myviewport.html` so you can decide on the manipulations to perform on it - in the example I showed a pre-set content width but you can manipulate it according to the device, the target page, etc., without compromising the autoscaling of the parent document.

Answer (score -1):

CSS/HTML example below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.myIframe {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 65.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; //<<--- THIS IS THE KEY 
  border: solid black 1px;
}
.myIframe iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text here</div>
<div class='myIframe'>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

NOTE:
This is to make an `<iframe>` responsive

Comment: Not at all what I was asking for, please read the question carefully