# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

I'm using [Framework7 sortable list](https://framework7.io/docs/sortable-list.html) and it works well, just that it doesn't trigger an event when the list is changed.

So I'm trying a few built-in events:

```
$('.sortable-handler').on('touchstart', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('touchstart');
});

$('.sortable-handler').on('touchmove', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('touchmove');
});

$('.sortable-handler').on('touchcancel', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('touchcancel');
});

$('.sortable-handler').mouseleave(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('mouseleave');
});
```

.. but all I get is:

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target
>   being treated as passive. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080

Which event should I look for to get the updated list on every sort?

Comment: This is a helpful article to understand the problem: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/scrolling-intervention/ Quoting: "impacted pages are fixed relatively easily by applying the touch-action CSS property whenever possible. If you wish to prevent all browser scrolling and zooming within an element apply touch-action: none to it."

Comment: Also note: If your `touch-action: none;` does not work, it is likely that you have applied another `overflow` value to your wrapper. Then define `touch-action: none; overflow: hidden;` for your element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To handle sortable list in Framework7 when user release currently sorting element in new position, you can use this code:

```
  $$('li').on('sortable:sort',function(event){
    alert("From " + event.detail.startIndex + " to " + event.detail.newIndex);
  });
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0zf5w4y7/

Comment: Ah man, how did you know about the event? Its not mentioned in their documentation.

Comment: They have. They mentioned it at the bottom of page. See the documentation https://framework7.io/docs/sortable-list.html#sortable-events

Comment: Seems the same behavior can be triggered with the [App Instance Event](https://framework7.io/docs/sortable-list.html#app-instance-events) `sortableSort`

Answer (score 117):

See this [blog post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/01/scrolling-intervention).  If you call `preventDefault` on every `touchstart` then you should also have a CSS rule to disable touch scrolling like

```css
.sortable-handler {
  touch-action: none;
}
```

Comment: @Rick Byers, how can I add `preventDefault()` for `wheel mousewheel DOMMouseScroll`

Comment: @Rick Beyers. can you provide an example? I'm having the same problem with jquery mobile `swipe` event

Comment: From the dev doc -  If you have a horizontal carousel consider applying `touch-action: pan-y pinch-zoom` to it so that the user can still scroll vertically and zoom as normal.

Comment: Atleast for chrome, with passive listeners, no need to call preventDefault. My situation is that my event listener and related functionality is inside a package, which I cannot touch/override, touch-action:none do help on the browser, but I will still see the warnings in the console log: Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener

Answer (score 60):

For me

```
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", this.mousewheel.bind(this), { passive: false });
```

did the trick (the `{ passive: false }` part).

Comment: it worked for me without bind mouseweel. I used it instead of e.preventDefault.
`window.addEventListener('wheel', { passive: false })`

Comment: Adding the passive:false after the pseudo function fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 30):

In plain JS add `{ passive: false }` as third argument

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doStuff(e);
}, { passive: false });
```

Comment: If you also need to use capturing instead of bubbling (meaning that the third argument would otherwise be `true`), the third argument should be `{capture: true, passive:false}`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener for a complete list of options for the third argument.

Comment: how can i do that for react's on listeners

Comment: but that will block the scroll event too, page will get freeze on focus of this particular item

Answer (score 8):

I am getting this issue when using owl carousal and scrolling the images.

So get solved just adding below CSS in your page.

```
.owl-carousel {
-ms-touch-action: pan-y;
touch-action: pan-y;
}
```

or

```
.owl-carousel {
-ms-touch-action: none;
touch-action: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was specifically looking for owl-carousal, and this worked like a charm :)

Comment: Great Answer. Owl Carousel things lmao

Answer (score 4):

just do a check before call `preventDefault`

```js
event.cancelable && event.preventDefault()
```

that's it!

More:

`touchstart`  &  `touchmove` default passive `true` due to perfomance, at most cases, you don't need to change that default optimize.

Comment: .cancelable worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Rick Buyers' answer

> See this blog post. If you call preventDefault on every touchstart
> then you should also have a CSS rule to disable touch scrolling like

```
.sortable-handler {
  touch-action: none;
}
```

here is how to do it in Javascript:

```
handlerList = document.getElementsByClassName("sortable-handler");
for (var i=0, len=handlerList.length|0; i<len; i=i+1|0) {
    handlerList[i].style.style.touchAction = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To still be able to scroll this worked for me

```
if (e.changedTouches.length > 1) e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution for react. this is for silly react number textfield scrolling problem which causes number change while moving with wheel. when you try to preventDefault onWheel property you get "*unable to prevent default inside passive event listener*" error. Here we add event listener in creation.

```
export default function CustomTextField({ ...other }) {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = ref.current;

    let isNumber = element.querySelector('input').type === 'number'
    if (isNumber) {
      element.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleWheel = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
  };

  return (
        <TextField
          {...field}
          ref={ref}
          fullWidth
          value={typeof field.value === 'number' && field.value === 0 ? '' : field.value}
          error={!!error}
          helperText={error?.message}
          {...other}
        />

  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a different solution for my code. I needed to disable the passive property for the touchend event. I was using jquery 3.5. You can try the below code:

```
jQuery.event.special.touchstart = {
        setup: function (_, ns, handle) {
            this.addEventListener('touchend', handle, { passive: !ns.includes('noPreventDefault') });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for React with TypeScript, I had to add and remove the event with passive set to false and call stopPropagation. CSS modifications were not needed.

```
  export const TableHeader = () : JSX.Element => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLTableCellElement | null>(null)

    useLayoutEffect((): (() => void) => {
      if (ref.current == null) return () => {}

      const stopPropagation = (e: WheelEvent): void => {
        e.stopPropagation()
      }

      ref.current.addEventListener('wheel', stopPropagation, {
        passive: false,
      })

      return (): void => {
        if (ref.current == null) return

        ref.current.removeEventListener('wheel', stopPropagation)
      }
    }, [])

    
    return <th ref={(r) => (ref.current = r)}>Header content</th>
}
```