# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event jquery error

Tags: jquery, touch

I am using a burger menu on my website, when I click it, I receive an error.

> [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080
>   jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1:4987

Here is the jQuery error:

```
  // If preventDefault exists, run it on the original event
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Shows the error is here.

    // Support: IE
    // Otherwise set the returnValue property of the original event to false
  } else {
    e.returnValue = false;
  }
},..
```

There were no problem previously, I don't know what has happened. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Assuming this is occurring on a touch device, then this is a possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42288386/519413

Comment: Do you think it is possible if i use; `body{touch-action: none;}`

Comment: No idea. Can't hurt to try

Comment: That way, it worked.

Comment: Glad it helped. Remember, the best way to fix an error is to paste it in to Google :)