# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event

Tags: javascript, preventdefault, touchstart

```
  $(document).on( 'click touchstart', '.js-menu-toggler', function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();

    triggerClass( $(this), 'fa-plus', 'fa-minus' );
  });

  $(document).on( 'click touchstart', '.js-accordion-toggler', function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
```

Hello! Im newbie in js and I need some help. There is 1 problem on mobiles (https://bmakeup.ru - footer with 2 menus) doesn't open sub menus right. It looks like double click. How can I fix this?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101723/unable-to-preventdefault-inside-passive-event-listener answer

Comment: @Anoop hello! I checked this, but I cant understand how to use this in my case, thats why I asked here, maybe someone can explain