# preventDefault() error in Chrome for mousewheel DOMMouseScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am getting this `preventDefault()` error in chrome console. I came across this [blog article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/01/scrolling-intervention) and tried few like adding `{ passive: false }` but no luck. How can I solve this?

I also read that using `return false;` instead is recommended. But I'm not sure if that's the solution in my case. So I am seeking your advise.

```
$(document).on('wheel mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(delay) return;

    delay = true;
    setTimeout(function(){delay = false},200)
        //some code
    });
})();
```

chrome error

`[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See...`

Thank you!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101723/unable-to-preventdefault-inside-passive-event-listener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information given in the error, going to the URL linked in said error, there is no obvious way to fix this with jQuery (could be, but I don't use jQuery, so I'm saying you can't) ... with regular javascript - you can, in the third argument, pass `{passive:false}` - which fixes this Chrome *"feature"*

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', fn, {passive: false});
document.addEventListener('mousewheel', fn, {passive: false});
document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', fn, {passive: false});

function fn(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(delay) return;

    delay = true;
    setTimeout(function(){delay = false},200)
        //some code
}
```

or if you want a more jQuery feel to your code, create a helper function

```
const addListeners = (tgt, list, fn, options) => list.split(' ').forEach(e => tgt.addEventListener(e, fn, options));
```

Then use it like

```
addListeners(document, 'wheel mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(delay) return;

    delay = true;
    setTimeout(function(){delay = false},200)
        //some code
    }, {passive: false}
);
```

> As mentioned in the comments, some OLD (very very old) browsers may not like this syntax `({passive:true|false})`
>
> So - you may want to feature detect the option - code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Safely_detecting_option_support

```
var passiveSupported = false;

try {
  var options = {
    get passive() { // This function will be called when the browser
                    //   attempts to access the passive property.
      passiveSupported = true;
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener("test", options, options);
  window.removeEventListener("test", options, options);
} catch(err) {
  passiveSupported = false;
}
```

before using it, so internet explorer doesn't have a little cry about it

Comment: Not using feature detection means the script will crash on browsers that don't [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=passive-event-listener) `passive`...

Comment: you've tested your little theory @Shikkediel - or are you just guessing?

Comment: No need to be rude. I've actually tested extensively. Besides that, it's in the Mozilla [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Safely_detecting_option_support).

Comment: Mozilla works fine, and I wasn't being rude - but I'll add a link to that in the answer - clearly useful for people that don't update their browser

Comment: Misplaced condescension comes across as rude. And IE11 is a browser that is still being maintained, for whatever reason the few people running Windows 7 might still use it. So "old" is hardly appropriate in that case. But I do appreciate the updated answer.