# ag-grid filter popup not opening on mobile

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

My filter popup is not opening on mobile/tablet devices, while it does work on desktop.

Techstack:

- NuxtJS Static application, Vue 2.6.14.
- "ag-grid-community": "^27.2.1",
- "ag-grid-enterprise": "^27.2.1",

Opened on desktop :

[image]

Error when clicking on the toggle to open a filter popup :

[image]

Comment: You show the problem but not even 1 line of your code. Also, did you make any google research with the exact error phrase? I tried and Google gives me lot of results, [also from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101723/unable-to-preventdefault-inside-passive-event-listener).  - [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, probably an issue regarding the way you use an event there, without actual code it's hard to help. Otherwise, a [repro] is quite welcome.