# Chrome browser error jquery-1.7.1 [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see following error in my website:

`[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.`
I searched a lot about this error and I already seen several topics about it but it couldn't help me. So I have to ask this question directly.
I know following part of code needs to edit

```
// if preventDefault exists run it on the original event
        if ( e.preventDefault ) {
            e.preventDefault();
```

or probably a part of this code:

```
jQuery.Event.prototype = {
    preventDefault: function() {
        this.isDefaultPrevented = returnTrue;

        var e = this.originalEvent;
        if ( !e ) {
            return;
        }

        // if preventDefault exists run it on the original event
        if ( e.preventDefault ) {
            e.preventDefault();

        // otherwise set the returnValue property of the original event to false (IE)
        } else {
            e.returnValue = false;          
        }
    },
    stopPropagation: function() {
        this.isPropagationStopped = returnTrue;

        var e = this.originalEvent;
        if ( !e ) {
            return;
        }
        // if stopPropagation exists run it on the original event
        if ( e.stopPropagation ) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        // otherwise set the cancelBubble property of the original event to true (IE)
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    },
    stopImmediatePropagation: function() {
        this.isImmediatePropagationStopped = returnTrue;
        this.stopPropagation();
    },
    isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse,
    isPropagationStopped: returnFalse,
    isImmediatePropagationStopped: returnFalse
};
```

After a lot of searches I did find that I should add  `{passive: false}` somewhere in above code but I don't know exactly where? (as I'm not programmer). Can you show it please
Also please do not close this question as a duplicate because it's not. thanks

Comment: Have you looked at other questions related to this error message, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101723/unable-to-preventdefault-inside-passive-event-listener

Comment: I did and it didn't helped me. that's why I'm asking question here.