# How to disable double click zooming on iPad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ipad

When I double click somewhere on a hml page there is zooming effect on iPad appears.

How could I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add a `meta` tag in your html code:

```
<meta 
 name='viewport' 
 content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0'/>
```

Comment: duplicate of:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614481/disable-double-tap-zoom-option-in-browser-on-touch-devices

Comment: @Mailyan thank you for a support.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the css property touch-action to none?

```css
.disable-zoom {
    touch-action: none;
}
```

This disables all the actions on the screen. 
If you want to disable just the double tap and perform other actions like pinch to zoom etc. use the following

```css
.disable-double-tap {
  touch-action: manipulate;
}
```

Comment: thank you for a support.