# Why does page zoom in when double-click button on web mobile

Tags: html, responsive-design, window-resize

I am really after information.

I have html page.
I set the viewpoints in the header like so:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes' />
<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style' content='black-translucent' />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

I have a button on the web page:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success DefaultButton" style="min-width: 40px;" onclick="">
```

On load it looks like this:

[image]

If I double tap button it goes like this:

[image]

Why? I am looking at stopping/cancel the user being able to double-tap. But why does this happen? The resize event is not invoked either.  I would like to know as it may affect other elements as well.

This was test on iPhone6...

Comment: Does this help? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614481/disable-double-tap-zoom-option-in-browser-on-touch-devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614481/disable-double-tap-zoom-option-in-browser-on-touch-devices)

Comment: @RobMoll thanks will build and check

Comment: @RobMoll yes it did. thanks :)