# How to prevent doubletap zoom in iOS and Android

Tags: jquery, events, zooming

I am building a web app using Jquery Mobile for use on a desktop, iPad and Android phone. I want the user to be able to tap a button to increment (or decrement) a value.  My code works fine on a desktop, but on the iPad and Android, when the user taps rapidly, the screen zooms instead of the value incrementing.
I have been trying to implement the solution here: [Safari iPad : prevent zoom on double-tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103842/safari-ipad-prevent-zoom-on-double-tap) (and in particular the refinement provided by Christopher Thomas.

Here is my code for the button and value:

```
    <div class="content">
        <div id ="status_page" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
                <div id="val">1</div>
                <div id="but" data-role="button">Click</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my event handler for a click on the button (btw - I think the parameters in Christopher's answer were the wrong way round):

```
        $(".content") .on("click",$("#but"),function(){
            var but_val = parseInt($("#val").text());
            $("#val").text(but_val+1);
        });
```

...and here is the nodoubletap function:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.nodoubletapzoom = function() {
    if($("html.touch").length == 0) return;

    $(this).bind('touchstart', function preventZoom(e){
        var t2 = e.timeStamp;
        var t1 = $(this).data('lastTouch') || t2;
        var dt = t2 - t1;
        var fingers = e.originalEvent.touches.length;
        $(this).data('lastTouch', t2);
        if (!dt || dt > 500 || fingers > 1){
            return; // not double-tap
        }
        e.preventDefault(); // double tap - prevent the zoom
        // also synthesize click events we just swallowed up
        $(this).trigger('click');
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

This function is trapping the double tap correctly. However, the trigger function at the end is not working (the event is not being fired).  If I substitute `$(this).trigger('click');` with `$('#but').trigger('click');` then everything works as it should.  I want this to work for a number of different buttons, so I need to be able to trigger the event based on the object that called the touchstart event. Can anyone help me to fix this please.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle here: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/GZEM7/11/ Version 11 works fine (it uses `$('#but')`) Version 10 does not work (it uses `$(this)`).

Comment: you don't explain here how you are applying the jquery function to your elements, for example, see my code where I say "$("body).nodoubletapzoom();" that is because I want to apply the function to the entire document, this could explain why you are getting the entire document and not the element selected?

Comment: also, I have a "content" node inside the body, I want to make sure all the events don't bubble up to the body element, so I am attaching jquery click handlers, etc to the content node using jquery.on() and then I attach the double tap handler to the body.  this means any event which escapes the "content" node and reaches body, I want to ignore, but I use "content" like a <<trap>> to catch the events, do you get it?

Comment: Hi Christopher - many thanks for your help.  I must be doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what - if you take a look at the jsfiddle, I have bound the nodoubletapzoom function to the body, and I have a content node inside the body.  If you can point out where I've gone wrong, I would be very grateful.

Comment: it should be "$(this).trigger("click")" and you changed it to $("#but").....

Comment: I played around a little bit and on my android galaxy note 10.1 this works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/GZEM7/14/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GZEM7/16/ works fine too, I only removed the IOS check you had at the top....

Comment: Hi - using $("#but") works fine - but using $(this) does not.  I want several buttons on the page, so I need $(this) to work so that I can fire the trigger for the button that was clicked.  Version 10 of the jsfiddle uses $(this) and does not work for me.

Comment: ahhh, I misunderstood that part obviously, let me check again

Comment: ok, this appears to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/GZEM7/18/ when I do that, the counter goes up like normal

Comment: can you mark my answer as correct then please, so I can collect the points :D

Answer (score 3):

ok, so "engeeaitch" the final solution was in the following jsfiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/GZEM7/18/

and the solution was to replace

```
$(this).trigger("click"):
```

with

```
$(e.target).trigger("click");
```

and of course, I removed your IOS testing because then it'll work on chrome and android devices :D

thats the final solution?  Cool! I'm going to update my code with the new version, I think it'll be better

the final code is:

```
$.fn.nodoubletapzoom = function() {
    $(this).bind('touchstart', function preventZoom(e){
        var t2 = e.timeStamp;
        var t1 = $(this).data('lastTouch') || t2;
        var dt = t2 - t1;
        var fingers = e.originalEvent.touches.length;
        $(this).data('lastTouch', t2);
        if (!dt || dt > 500 || fingers > 1){
            return; // not double-tap
        }
        e.preventDefault(); // double tap - prevent the zoom
        // also synthesize click events we just swallowed up
        $(e.target).trigger('click');
    });
};
})(jQuery);

$(document).on('pageinit',"#status_page", function(){
        $("body").nodoubletapzoom();
        $(".content").on("click", "#but", function() {
            var curr_val = parseInt($("#val").text());
            $("#val").text(curr_val + 1);
        });
});
```

Comment: Can you change it to `noDoubleTapZoom` instead of `nodoubletapzoom`? That would make me happy

Comment: well, you can do whatever you want, just copy the code and change it however you like.