# How to avoid the 300ms delay when clicking a checkbox on iOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I'm developing a webapp for iOS using jQueryMobile. I'm trying to avoid the 300ms delay on click, as I'm not using the double click event.

I've tried *FastClick.js*, but it's not fully compatible with jQM, as the event is sometimes fired twice, especially with checkboxes and radio buttons.

I use the *needsclick* class for those cases, but in some complex cases, it seems to be ignored, so I still have the event being fired twice. Because of this, I removed *FastClick* and am using the `vclick` event instead. It works fine for the click event, but it doesn't effect change events, and there is no `vchange` event.

I can't use the `vclick` event for checkboxes, as I need to test if it's checked.

How can I avoid the 300ms delay on click?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthieubrunet/uv5x7fmq/)

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" value="1">
<label for="check">check</label>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("input").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).next().css("color","green");
    } else {
        $(this).next().css("color","black");
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried this? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: meta tags has nothing to do with events @APAD1

Comment: @Omar Actually, [yes it does](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away) for some mobile browsers anyway.

Comment: I didn't tried, but I read somewhere that it's not supported by iOS

Comment: @newbiedoodle thanks for your corrections, but why did you remove my code ? The guidelines state that we must post code even with a fiddle : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Matthieu I didn't know that -- I'll readd it now. My bad.

Comment: Perharps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9728511

Comment: I read it three times, but can't figure how it could help me... My problem is not about douple-tap, bu about change event...