# Facebook on safari ipad: how to disable zoom

Tags: facebook, ipad, iframe

I have a facebook page tab (in iframe).
In my app i disable user zoom :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

On ipad when i double-click on my iframe, all the facebook page zoom (and the iframe with my app). 
How can i disable this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safari iPad : prevent zoom on double-tap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103842/safari-ipad-prevent-zoom-on-double-tap)

Comment: it's not the same request. I can detect a double tape but I can't stop the zoom if the app is in a facebook iframe, i want to do that.

Comment: if the answers in that other thread don´t work because it´s in an iframe, then there is nothing you can do, i guess. but did you try all the suggestions? i´ve also found many other stackoverflow threads about the double tap issue with lots of answers you can try.

Comment: yes i'm trying at the moment several tests, but no issue for the moment